# Run Perl CGI script in Tomcat 7.0.70

Tags: perl, tomcat7, cgi

I am trying to host my cgi page in the Tomcat 7.0.70 webserver in linux box.

I have done the below steps and also I am unable to view my cgi page in the browser.

1. I have created a CGI script named as "test.pl".

> ```
> #!/usr/bin/perl
> print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
> foreach (sort keys %ENV)
> {
>   print "<b>$_</b>: $ENV{$_}<br>\n";
> }
> ```

2. I have created a dir "myprog" in ~/myweb/apache-tomcat-7.0.70/webapps/ path.
3. Then I have created a dir "WEB-INF" in ~/myweb/apache-tomcat-7.0.70/webapps/myprog/
4. Then I have created a "cgi" directory inside the "myprog/WEB-INF/" and placed the test.pl file.
5. Then I have removed the comments from web.xml for the below lines , which is located in  ~/myweb/apache-tomcat-7.0.70/conf/

   cgi
       org.apache.catalina.servlets.CGIServlet
       
         debug
         0
       
       
         cgiPathPrefix
         WEB-INF/cgi
       
        5

   And, servlet-mapping area as well.
6. After that I have downloaded the servlets-cgi-4.1.36.jar and servlets-ssi-5.0.16.jar files into ~/myweb/apache-tomcat-7.0.70/lib/
7. Then, I tried to run the file from my windows machine from the web browser: http://devserver.com/myprog/ and it returns the message as

   HTTP Status 404 - /myprog/
   type Status report
   message /myprog/
   description The requested resource is not available.
   Apache Tomcat/7.0.70

Please someone assist/suggest to get this resolved.

Comment: Usually tomcat listen on port 8080

Comment: I have configured a port 9080 and already some java applications are running

Comment: then try to call http://devserver.com/9080myprog/

Comment: I have tried with http://devserver.com:9080/myprog/ as well. The same 
HTTP Status 404 - /myprog/
type Status report
message /myprog/
description The requested resource is not available.
Apache Tomcat/7.0.70

Comment: Did I miss anything? Please can I have any procedure document to deploy my cgi scripts in tomcat 7.0

Comment: Server log should give more details

Comment: INFO: Marking servlet cgi as unavailable
Jul 21, 2016 9:49:04 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet [cgi] in web application [/docs] threw load() exception
java.lang.SecurityException: Access to class [class org.apache.catalina.servlets.CGIServlet] is forbidden. It is a restricted class. A web application must be configured as privileged to be able to load it
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.checkAccess(DefaultInstanceManager.java:517)
        at

Answer (score 0):

The server log excerpt that you posted indicates that your web application needs to be privileged to use CGIServlet.  In /webapps/myprog/META-INF, add a file context.xml with
<Context privileged="true">
</Context>